# pandas dataframe groupby over consecutive duplicates and sum the values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, sum

In pandas dataframe, I'm totally confused of how to use the method of `groupby()` over consecutive duplicates by sum values in column

Let's say I have the following DataFrame `df` :

```
index   type    value
  0    profit    11     
  1    profit    10
  2    loss      -5
  3    profit    50
  4    profit    15
  5    loss     -30
  6    loss     -25
  7    loss     -10
```

what I'm looking to is:

```
index   type    grand
  0    profit    21  # total of 11 + 10 = 21
  1    loss      -5  # the same value as this row NOT consecutive duplicated
  2    profit    65  # total of 50 + 15 = 65
  3    loss     -65  # total of -30 -25 -10 = -65
```

What I tried to do:

```
 df['grand'] = df.groupby(df['type'].ne(df['type'].shift()).cumsum()).cumcount()
```

but it gives me counting the consecutive duplicated

I tried to iterate through the rows with several solutions but all were failed

Thanks so much!

Comment: Why are you using `.cumcount()` in the first place?

Comment: `@wjandrea` I was using `.cumcount()` to reuse later on when iterating over each row to calculate the consecutive sum , and thanks for the clarification, I modified my question to `loss -65` instead of `loss -30`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `.cumcount()` use sum:

```py
out = (
    df.groupby(df["type"].ne(df["type"].shift()).cumsum(), as_index=False)
    .agg({"type": "first", "value": "sum"})
    .rename(columns={"value": "grand"})
)

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
     type  grand
0  profit     21
1    loss     -5
2  profit     65
3    loss    -65
```

Comment: OP also wants a different column name, so: `.agg(type=('type', 'first'), grand=('value', 'sum'))`

Comment: You can also pass `as_index=False` to `groupby` to save dropping the index later.

Comment: @wjandrea I've changed the answer, thanks!